# Option of Permanently use no longer in SVN Subversion?

Tags: svn

In the past, there was this option prompt to save the password (p)ermanently.

This was useful, since one could delete ~/.subversion and reconfigure it simply and cleanly.

Today you are obliged to enter again and again the password. So much time consuming. Not good at all, when you are at work working on a large scale project. No Choice?

Using SVN Subversion without re-entering password each time.

```
svn, version 1.9.5 (r1770682)
   compiled Aug  9 2017, 03:04:58 on arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
```

Would you know possible solutions, ideally directly from a single command line with options to leave again this fabulous "(p)ermanently" back to us?

Answer (score 1):

1. If it's old host, well-configured workplace:

   - Check **carefully** your `~/.subversion/config`for changes: you can have *now* "don't store passwords" or "don't store unenrypted passwords" or ...(?)
   - Check enabled password's stores - does they work now and all needed preliminary teps executed (namely - keyring)
2. If it's new place - again: check config or used command's options:

   - `store-passwords = no` in config
   - `--no-auth-cache` option in any command, which will require authorization